# app not displaying x and y coordinates

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I m a beginner to android so i made app to display just simple x and y coordinates.

```
package company.com.bucky;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static int X;
public static int Y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final TextView firsttextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

      firsttextview.setText("X : " + X + "\nY : " + Y);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     this.Y = (int) event.getX();
      this.Y = (int) event.getY();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

SO when i run the app i just shows the value of x and y just 0..and no change in value when i touch the screen.Thx in advance for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onTouch handler only sets the static variables, but does not update the text view.

Put `firsttextview.setText("X : " + X + "\nY : " + Y);`
into the onTouch handler.

Comment: how to i access firsttextview inside it..??

Comment: Use also findViewById